# tensorflow optimizing sparse_tensor_dense_matmul operation on GPU

Tags: tensorflow

Is optimizing sparse_tensor_dense_matmul operation possible in tensorflow on GPU?
I use tensoflow 1.2.1 with CUDA 8.
Error example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    st = tf.SparseTensor(
        tf.constant([[0, 0], [1, 1]], dtype=tf.int64),
        tf.constant([1.2, 3.4], dtype=tf.float32),
        tf.constant([2, 2], dtype=tf.int64)
    ) 
    v = tf.Variable([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]], dtype=tf.float32)
    st = tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(st, v)
    st = tf.reduce_min(st)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    trainer = optimizer.minimize(st)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(trainer))
```

Results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_tf3.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(sess.run(trainer))
  File "/media/awork/home/astepochkin/drecs/repo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/media/awork/home/astepochkin/drecs/repo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/media/awork/home/astepochkin/drecs/repo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
    options, run_metadata)
  File "/media/awork/home/astepochkin/drecs/repo/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device for operation 'gradients/SparseTensorDenseMatMul/SparseTensorDenseMatMul_grad/strided_slice_1': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
     [[Node: gradients/SparseTensorDenseMatMul/SparseTensorDenseMatMul_grad/strided_slice_1 = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT64, begin_mask=1, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=1, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=2, _device="/device:GPU:0"](Const, gradients/SparseTensorDenseMatMul/SparseTensorDenseMatMul_grad/strided_slice_1/stack, gradients/SparseTensorDenseMatMul/SparseTensorDenseMatMul_grad/strided_slice_1/stack_1, gradients/SparseTensorDenseMatMul/SparseTensorDenseMatMul_grad/strided_slice_1/stack_2)]]
```

Comment: I have added a feature request:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12475

Answer (score 0):

It may make sense to disable hard device placement:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    st = tf.SparseTensor(
        tf.constant([[0, 0], [1, 1]], dtype=tf.int64),
        tf.constant([1.2, 3.4], dtype=tf.float32),
        tf.constant([2, 2], dtype=tf.int64)
    ) 
    v = tf.Variable([[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]], dtype=tf.float32)
    st = tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(st, v)
    st = tf.reduce_min(st)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    trainer = optimizer.minimize(st)

with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(trainer))
```

You can also [log device placements](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu#logging_device_placement),
 which may be useful for figuring out whether the kernels you care about are on the GPU.

There are [host memory fake GPU kernels registered for int32 strided slice](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/15b953a5d8254a89bcd7e0f3dc9843c101846cb2/tensorflow/core/kernels/strided_slice_op.cc#L438), but not for `int64`. I would open a pull request / feature request on Github to add `int64` host memory kernels (effectively just copying the `int32` versions) if you need/want hard device placement.

For background, strided slice is getting used in the gradient of `SparseTensorDenseMatMul`. There's generally no benefit to running these kinds of indexing operations on the GPU, so they get registered as GPU kernels which run on the CPU in order to avoid the kinds of hard device placement bookkeeping issues you've run into.